# Posting object to Facebook via Open Graph with a specific date, but the date isn't working

Tags: facebook, date, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

I am posting to a user's Facebook Timeline from my app, and am having some trouble with dates. The user is initiating the post to Facebook from my app. The object they are posting is an event that occurred in the last few days.

This is the post request:

```
RestClient.post "https://graph.facebook.com/me/app:action", :access_token=>access_token_here, :object=>object_url, :tags => some_tags, :start_time =>"2011-11-08T04:00:00Z", :end_time => "2011-11-08T05:00:00Z"
```

After I do this for my own Facebook account, the event appears, in the Facebook activity log, in the current date, not the date specified by the start_time.

I have also tried using epoch time, but there's no difference:

```
RestClient.post "https://graph.facebook.com/me/app:action", :access_token=>access_token_here, :object=>object_url, :tags => some_tags, :start_time =>"1320724800", :end_time => "1320728400"
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Since the Timeline is still in beta, this might be a Facebook bug. There is also a [similar one](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/164840033604092?browse=search_4ee536ee60eae7105776814) already filed. I would suggest you file this one as a new bug [here](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/) and see if someone can reproduce it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried writing the date in different formats, especially this one:

```
:start_time =>"2011-11-08 04:00:00"
```

I'm using this format to post dates to Facebook and it's working as expected, without timezone issues.

Answer (score 0):

Did you also try it without timezone information (without the Z)?
Here is the code which worked for me (javascript):

```
function postRestaurant() {
    FB.api('me/MY_APP_NAMESPACE:have_lunch?\
    start_time=2000-12-12T04:00:00&\
    expires_in=7200&\
    restaurant=' + OBJECT_URI), 'post', function (response) {
        if (!response || response.error) {
            console.log('postRestaurant: Error occured => ' + response.error.message);
        } else {
            console.log('postRestaurant: Post was successful! Action ID: ' + response.id);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We experienced issues where FB is ignoring the end time  and posting all actions as past tense instead of future.

This has been raised as a bug. as a workaround weve set the verb as future tense for both... for now.